# CodeIgniter - Loading an application package prevents loading of view and dealing with collisions

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've been learning CodeIgniter and was just experimenting with adding Application Packages.

In the default install I've added a package path to the third_party folder that contains a single view, and then I want it to continue loading the default welcome_message.  Separately this all works fine, but together the welcome_message view file can't be found apparently.  Reading on in the docs at http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/loader.html it mentions view collisions, and talks about setting the second parameter. Okay no problem, there isn't another view named welcome_message, but I do what then mention according to the example provided, which sets it to FALSE to get the welcome_message to display, but that doesn't work.

In fact I have to set it to TRUE to get it to work, which is the exact opposite of the docs.  Can someone explain this logic reversal? and regarding view naming collisions due to a lack of a description in the docs does this mean setting the second param to whichever boolean prevents collisions and allow full use of all views regardless of naming?  Or does it simply throw an error instead of loading the improper view?

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->add_package_path(APPPATH . 'third_party/foo_bar/', FALSE);
        $this->load->view('foo_bar');
        $this->load->view('welcome_message'); // throws err on FALSE and loads on TRUE in add_package_path() call
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `$this->load->view('foo_bar');`

reset the path using `$this->load->remove_package_path();`

When you use `add_package_path` CI will check that folder for all path requests. This is fine when you are working with a self contained app. When you are done with that and want to access the "regular" CI paths for views etc, you need to remove the package path first.

Comment: Hi @raidenance, I did consider that, but what if you're using a shared codebase that you are using a variety of different libraries, helpers, models, etc all the time? That seems like it would create unnecessary bloat, and be quite inefficient.  Is that something that is an accepted practice with CodeIgniter?

Comment: @mtpultz AFAIK, there is no work around for this. As you are well aware, CI is supposed to be a very lightweight framework with a minimalist design so it does not provide too many functionalities off the shelf. If your app is not VERY big, you can also consider splitting them inside CI's own folders and segregating them using subfolders like - library/myApp,  model/myApp, view/myApp etc...

Comment: Hmmm that wouldn't work.  We are making an app, but using a shared code base with other projects so to keep it clean having the shared resources in the third_party folder is the best solution to keep the separation, and allow for easy maintenance of both repositories.

Comment: @mtpultz - ok I looked at the document and I think this is what is happening. When you add FALSE, the add_package_path is the only path that will be considered, which is why you get error .When you add TRUE, all the view paths are checked and the first match is loaded. This can cause potential clashes, but in your case since welcome_message is unique you should be fine. However you will need to ensure the app does not have name clashes for any files with CI

Comment: Thanks @raidenance that makes sense, I was just looking at the function call and coming to a similar conclusion.  I noticed they do a union between the arrays.